# Flutter issues after flutter upgrade to Flutter 1.11.0 (Mac OS)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

After upgrading flutter to 1.11.0 it is showing this error below when trying to run a project.

> Couldn't read file LocalFile:
>   '/Users/h/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audio_recorder-1.0.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jordanalcaraz/audiorecorder/audiorecorder/AudioRecorderPlugin.kt'
>   even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read
>   permission and try again.

Comment: Are you using latest version of the plugin?

Comment: yes I checked I am using the latest.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Comment: flutter cache repair  might work or just delete all cache folder

Comment: @LOG_TAG I've deleted the packages folder, to no avail. Is this the one you refer to? Which one should I repair/delete, and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague found this:

https://github.com/ZaraclaJ/audio_recorder/issues/46

And according to DyaryRaoof the solution is:

*I am on the master branch. This error appears in iOS.
To solve it you need to locate your audio_recorder plugin inside flutter. then change the name of it's last child folder on android. You have to change it from audio_recorder to audiorecorder(remove the underscore).*

Or just wait for the package maintainer to solve that issue.